# Filter JTable lines edition based on an Object

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, rowfilter

I have an object that have a method `displayable()`, as you guess it returns true when displayed in my implementation of `AbstractTableModel`.

Here is how `getValueAt(...)` looks like :

```
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        switch(col) {
        case 2:
            return DataServiceFactory.gaService().getActionData(row, id).getMode();
```

Based on a session, I get a specific set of objects.

I want to use the filter feature by Java, but don't know well if there is not better alternatives ? How about the edition (required) ?
And finally how to say to the filter "only display thoses `ActionData` that return true when you their `displayable()` method" ?

Comment: click to the rowfilter tag, if without success then to post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilale, with hardcoded value in local variable for AbstractTable Model

Comment: Hello @mKorbel, and merry Christmas (or whatever holiday you celebrate) to you and to your family.